# Left join throws error when filtering grid collection in Magento

Tags: magento, join, collections, filter, error-handling

I need to add a join to my order collection with my custom table.

For this I have use this below code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()
               ->joinLeft(array(
                  "t1" => 'fp_sellecrcommision_data'),                 
                  "main_table.increment_id = t1.store_order_id", 
                  array("commiisiion_status" => "t1.commiisiion_status")
               );
    $collection->addFieldToFilter("store_id",$storeid )
               ->addAttributeToFilter("status","complete");
```

Which is working fine. But when I am applying filter it is throwing below error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'commiisiion_status' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`store_id` = '1') AND (`status` = 'complete') AND (`commiisiion_status` = '0')
```

This is the structure of my custom table:

[image]

And below is my custom column in grid:

```
$this->addColumn('commiisiion_status', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sellercommision')->__('Commision Status'),
    'index' => 'commiisiion_status',
    'type' => 'options',
    'options' => XYZ_Sellercommision_Block_Adminhtml_Sellercommision_Storeorders::commisionsStatusesArray(),                
));
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you plz add your database structure to your answer: `describe sales_flat_order_grid;` and `describe fp_sellecrcommision_data;`

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have solved this by using below _commissionFilterCallBack function

```
    protected function _commissionFilterCallBack($collection, $column)
    {
    //Put your logic here..!!
    $value =  $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    $comission_paid_orders = array();

    $commissionstatus_model  = Mage::getModel("commissionstatus/commissionstatus")->getCollection();
    foreach($commissionstatus_model as $commissionstatus){
            $comission_paid_orders[] =  $commissionstatus['order_imcrement_id'];
        }
    if ($value=="pending") 
        {
            if(count($comission_paid_orders)==0){
                return $this;
                }
            else{
                $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter("increment_id",array("nin"=>$comission_paid_orders));
                return $this;
            }
        }
    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("t1.commission_status like ?", "%$value%");

        return $this;
    }
```